# What are these? [Unknown Hardware]

Tags: hardware

After doing some cleaning over the weekend, I found these left to us from the prior owner of my home.  I've never come across these before, but they look to be lag screws within some sort of hangar or mount. Can't say I've ever seen these during a trip to the hardware store, nor can I find any location in my home where they're actually in use.  Frankly, I'm baffled.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

What are these, and more importantly what are they used for?

Comment: Probably some proprietary part to some product. Could be shipping braces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly Appliance shipping locks.  Probably for a washer or dryer.  Keeps the vulnerable internal parts from banging around during shipment (for instance, the washer drum).

Usually are just thrown away after installation.

Comment: That would play well with the fact that they were left for me by the prior owners along with all sorts of random stuff which turned out to be junk.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: That's exactly what they are, albeit not for the drum component, for attaching the entire appliance to the wood shipping pallet. The pallet has pre-drilled holes, the frame of the appliance has holes that the "clip" part attaches to on the assembly line. At the end of the line a worked lines up the pallet holes to where these little wood screw threads are and turns the nut on the other end. That drives the wood screw into the pallet, then when it bottoms out, the red plastic parts squeezes down and expands into the holes in the frame of the appliance, jamming into them to hold it in place.